# Show that $EX_N$ is just a Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, measure-theory

Here $X_N = XI(0 < X \le N)$ and expectation is defined as

$$EX = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n}P\Bigg(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n} < X \le \frac{i}{\sqrt n}\bigg) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n}\Bigg(F(\frac{i}{\sqrt n}) - F(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n})\bigg)$$

and so by definition $EX$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral

$$EX = \int xdF(x) $$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function. The goal is to show that

$$EX_N = \int_0^N(F(N) - F(x))dx $$

I don't have much experience with analysis or measure theory so I googled the definition of the Reimann integral and came up with this equality

$$EX_N = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n} \bigg(F(N) - F(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n})\bigg)\frac N n$$

They look very similar - the first has a step function $\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n}$ and equal-spaced intervals where to look for probability and the second has a step function of where to look for probability ($F(N) - F(\frac{i-1}{\sqrt n})$) and a constant interval $\frac N n$.  I tried putting the two parts in correspondence with strategic indicator functions but couldn't make it work.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your question. Who is $X$? Who is $F$?  Where does your expression for "expectation" come from??

Comment: $F$ is the cumulative distribution function and $X$ is a random variable of which $X_N$ is the subset restricted to $(0, N]$. The definition of expectation is provided in the problem, it's the classical expectation definition.

Comment: The "classical" expectation definition would be the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_{\mathbb R} x\ \mathsf dF(x),
$$
with $F$ the distribution function of $F$.

Comment: In general, for a nonnegative random variable $X$, we have $$\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\ \mathsf dx. $$ (Tonelli's theorem.) From here it is not difficult to derive the integral expression for $\mathbb E[X_N]$.

Comment: I thought that the definition for $EX$ I gave is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral. I edited for clarity. The goal here is to prove what you mentioned (Tonelli's theorem) by letting $EX_N \to EX$, but first I need to show that the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral above coincides with the Riemann integral, which is what I am having trouble with.